# Formula to count alternate columns given specific value

Tags: excel, sumproduct

In the spreadsheet attached, I am try to get a percent and count of values given the detection code associated with it in the adjacent column (U, J+, R, etc.). If there is a number with no code, it counts as detected. If there is a number with the letter U, it counts as U, etc.

I need to do this for all rows for the spreadsheet. This is a snapshot of a much larger dataset, so I'd like to automate it as much as possible.

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Units | Chemical/Sample ID | 1 | Detection code | 2 | Detection code | 3 | Detection code | 4 | Detection code | 5 | Detection code | 6 | Detection code | 7 | Detection code | Percent Detected | Count Detected | Percent U | Count U | Percent J | Count J | Percent R | Count R | Count per Row |
| ug/mL | 4-Nitrophenol |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 |  | 0 |  |  |  |  | 0 |
| ug/mL | Acetaldehyde |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 260 |  | 10 | U |  | 1 |  | 1 |  |  |  |  | 2 |
| ug/mL | Aluminum |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 7700 |  | 200 | U |  | 1 |  | 1 |  |  |  |  | 2 |
| ug/mL | Arsenic |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1.4 |  | 1 | U |  | 1 |  | 1 |  |  |  |  | 2 |
| ug/mL | Benzo(a)anthracene |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 |  | 0 |  |  |  |  | 0 |
| ug/mL | Benzo(a)pyrene |  |  |  |  |  |  | 10 | U |  |  | 0.19 | U | 0.19 | U |  | 0 |  | 3 |  |  |  |  | 3 |
| ug/mL | Benzo(g,h,i)perylene |  |  |  |  |  |  | 6.7 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 |  | 0 |  |  |  |  | 1 |
| mg/L | Calcium |  |  |  |  |  |  | 380 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 |
| mg/L | Chloride |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0.19 | U |  |  | 110 |  | 96 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 3 |
| ug/mL | Chloroform |  |  |  |  |  |  | 200 |  |  |  | 1 | U | 1 | U |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 3 |
| ug/mL | Chloromethane | 0.19 | U |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 |
| ug/mL | Chromium-Hexavalent |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0.5 | U |  |  | 10 | U | 10 | U |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 3 |
| ug/mL | Cobalt |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 6.7 |  | 0.3 | U |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2 |
| ug/mL | Copper | 96 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 380 |  | 18 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 3 |
| ug/mL | Dibenz(a,h)anthracene | 1 | U |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0.19 | U | 0.19 | U |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 3 |
| ug/mL | Formaldehyde |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 200 |  | 10 | U |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2 |
| ug/mL | Hexachloroethane | 10 | U |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 |
| ug/mL | Hydrazine | 0.3 | U |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0.5 | U | 0.5 | U |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 3 |
| ug/mL | Iron | 18 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 22000 |  | 160 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 3 |
| ug/mL | Manganese | 0.19 | U |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 8700 |  | 59 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 3 |
| ug/mL | Nickel | 10 | U |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 25 |  | 10 | U |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 3 |
| mg/L | Nitrate |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0.3 |  | 0.24 | J+ |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2 |
| mg/L | Nitrite |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0.05 | U | 0.05 | R |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2 |
| ng/L | N-Nitrosodimethylamine (NDMA) | 0.34 | J | 2.1 | U | 2 | U | 0.77 | J | 0.8 | J | 2.3 | U | 2.1 | U |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 7 |
| ng/L | N-Nitroso-di-n-propylamine (NDPA) | 2.2 | U | 2.1 | U | 2 | U | 2 | U | 2.1 | U |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 5 |
| ug/mL | Phenanthrene |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 |
| mg/L | Sodium |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 |

I've used this code:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(C3:O3)*(ISBLANK(D3:P3))))
```

and

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(C5:O5)*(ISTEXT(D5:P5))))
```

But I cannot figure out how to select for a specific text: "U", "J", "R", etc.

Comment: Please provide your data in [Table Markdown format](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) you can copy and paste it. Part of your explanation doesn't refer to a specific column, so I don't know what is the logic, for example, there are several section code columns.

Comment: Hi David, I added it in Table Markdown format for you. Per row, I need to get percent and count of detection codes: blank, U, R, J+, or J. Its tricky for me because the detection code is in alternate columns alternating with the values.

Comment: Thanks Rachel, in general the idea is to use a toy sample that represents your problem, but it is fine. Is the number of columns (the columns with number and Detection Code) fixed or variable?, if not what is the pattern?

Comment: Got it. The columns alternate every other (by number and detection code) for the entire set. They can be moved, but this data set is very, very large, and each column cluster is sorted by location, which varies in size, so you may have a group cluster that is 15 columns or 25.

Comment: Rachel, check my answer below, what I did was to identify the column header of interest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your expected result, it sounds like the Detection Code value doesn't matter. The following formula identifies the columns of interest checking that they are numbers. You can use the following formula:

```
=LET(in, A1:Z28, h, TAKE(in,1), fn, 1-ISNA(XMATCH(ISNUMBER(h),TRUE)),
 BYROW(DROP(in,1), LAMBDA(x, SUM(N(FILTER(x, fn,0)<>"")))))
```

You can also try the following which replaces `BYROW` array function with `MMULT`.

```
=LET(in,A1:Z28, h,TAKE(in,1), fn, 1-ISNA(XMATCH(ISNUMBER(h),TRUE)),
 idx, FILTER(SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(h)),fn), MMULT(N(CHOOSECOLS(DROP(in,1), idx)<>0), 
  SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(idx),,,0)))
```

[image: output]