# Max value if not this in excel

Tags: excel, max, maxifs

With the following data set, I want to find the max and min value across rows, and then report the corresponding letter associated with the value. So if the max value is 0.19 and the associated letter is U, then I would like it to populate in a separate column 0.19 and U. There are some that are blank (no letters), so if it is the max/min value and the column next to it is blank, then I would like it to say "blank".

| 1 | U | 1 | U |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
| 0.19 | U | 0.19 | U |
|  |  |  |  |
| 0.19 | U | 0.19 | U |
|  |  |  |  |
| 2.3 | U | 2.1 | U |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
| 7700 |  | 200 | U |
| 1.4 |  | 1 | U |
|  |  |  |  |
| 10 | U | 10 | U |
| 6.7 |  | 0.3 | U |
| 380 |  | 18 |  |
| 22000 |  | 160 |  |
| 8700 |  | 59 |  |
| 25 |  | 10 | U |
|  |  |  |  |
| 110 |  | 96 |  |
| 0.3 |  | 0.24 | J+ |
| 0.05 | U | 0.05 | R |
| 260 |  | 10 | U |
| 200 |  | 10 | U |
| 0.5 | U | 0.5 | U |

Comment: Look into `MAX`, `MATCH` and `INDEX`

Comment: Also check out large() and small().

Comment: @RachelGladstone, two days ago you posted the following question: [Formula to count alternate columns given specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75931034/formula-to-count-alternate-columns-given-specific-value), and you get some answer. It would be nice to accept, vote or provide any feedback on your old question, before keep posting additional questions. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you share some relevant data including the expected results where the logic is obvious why a letter has been chosen? I mean there isn't a single record where more than one letter could be chosen: either the letters are equal, or one is missing or the values are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess You want these expected results

[image]

I Edited the Answer:

```
=LET(dt,CHOOSECOLS(WRAPROWS(TRANSPOSE(A2:D2),2),1),ltrs,CHOOSECOLS(WRAPROWS(TRANSPOSE(A2:D2),2),2),mx,MAX(dt),mn,MIN(dt),mxl,INDEX(ltrs,MATCH(mx,dt,0)),mnl,INDEX(ltrs,MATCH(mn,dt,0)),HSTACK(mx,IF(mxl="","Blank",mxl),mn,IF(mnl="","Blank",mnl)))
```

I hope this will give you an idea. You have to drag it. or Otherwise if you can use recursive lambda, it will give you the omitted array in one go instead of dragging the formula for thousand rows.

Comment: I need this to be across rows, not columns, so instead of comparing A to B, I need it to compare to all in row 3 for example. I have the latest version of excel.

Comment: If this is not the required output, please edit your question and provide some required output data along with the original data table's small chunk, so it will give us an idea what output you want from what data. make an output table and put make a screenshot of what actually result should be.